# Для чего нужен API?

Tags: api, терминология

Необходимо краткое и ясное объяснение понятия API.
Что это такое?
В каких случаях используется?

Answer (score 7):

API - это Application Programming Interface, то есть программный интерфейс, через который приложение получает доступ к чему либо. В случае библиотеки, например, это набор функций, которые библиотека экспортирует. Windows API это набор функций и интерфейсов, через которые приложение получает доступ к разным функциям и сервисам Windows. То есть любой программный объект, который предоставляет какие-то сервисы другим программным объектам, по определению имеет некое API.

Answer (score 2):

Если объяснять на пальцах, то есть языки программирования общего назначения - Си, Джава, Пайтон итд. А есть отдельные "мини-языки", на которых общаются компоненты одной или нескольких тесно связанных между собой программ, именуемые API. Эти "языки" (а точнее интерфейсы) обычно пишут не "большие дядьки сверху", а сами разработчики программ, для своих нужд.

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще один вариант объяснения, отвечающий на вопросы:

> Что такое API?
>   В каких случаях используется?

API это язык, регламентированный способ, общения одной компьютерной программы с другой для совместного исполнения какой-нибудь общей задачи, когда одна программа выполняют запросы другой. Т.е. интерфейс программирования приложений.

*Аналогия из жизни военного:*

Пример, из жизни военных которые проходят регулярную службу в армии, а в частности как сотрудничают в определенной области их жизнедеятельности. Не знаю, имеете ли вы понятие об армии как таковой, но я думаю схожую аналогию вы уже перенесете на обычную жизнь. Да, существует много родов войск со своей спецификой службы, но мы остановимся на обычной сухопутной воинской части, где есть караульная служба.
Итак, как большинство знает, в армии служат различные люди, из разных регионов, с разным уровнем подготовки к данной сфере деятельности. Условная воинская часть заступает в караул (т.е. вид наряда в котором вооружённое подразделение, выполняет боевую задачу по охране чего-либо), из краткого описания понятно, что туда заступает определенное количество людей у которых будут разные обязанности, т.е. роли на время отведенное для этой цели.
И вот тут как раз момент про API. Так как каждый выполняет свои роли, им необходимо как-то знать, что из себя представляет та или иная роль в данном наряде, и как они должны на протяжении условно отведенного времени взаимодействовать.
Роли: Начальник караула, разводящий, часовой , ну и т.д.
Для бесперебойного взаимодействия военнослужащих в карауле существует Устав (API в нашем случае), в котором четко расписаны роли и инструкции (алгоритмы). Изучив Устав, каждый заступающий в караул понимает что и когда он должен делать и как взаимодействовать с другими. Т.е. API - это определенный стандарт, позволяющий всем все понимать.

*Немного о разработке*

Практически любой разработчик программного обеспечения, может написать собственный интерфейс для взаимодействия и обмена информацией и вот чтоб мы могли грамотно пользоваться его творением, необходимо ознакомится с документацией (т.е. описанием способов ее (программы) взаимодействия с другими программами) - оно же API.