# Получение данных из гугл таблицы и отправка юзеру в телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать получение данных из гугл таблицы https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BDNS4Ab86wdwSHUitC8UO5Nj46e91wB49YBFJYrsKPU/edit#gid=0 по запросу юзера на питоне и aiogram. Допустим:
В боте есть 3 инлайн-кнопки [Сегодня, Завтра, Другая дата]
При нажатии на кнопку [Сегодня], код смотрит в таблицу и берет от туда информацию и присылает пользователю инфу в таком формате:
Дата: 31.05
Сотрудники:
Адель [ 10-22 }
и тд.

При выборе [Другая дата], бот просит ввести дату в формате ДД.ММ и смотрит на ту дату которую написал юзер, если этой даты нет в таблице, то пишет об отсутствии даты.
Еще дело в том, что табличные данные каждый месяц перезаписываются в эти же ячейки, с обновлением месяца и режима работы. Поэтому запрос должен именно смотреть на дату и брать инфу ту что под датой.

Comment: Использовать апи гугл таблиц

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ruSO! Попробуйте поизучать библиотеку `gspread`, как пример.. -> https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/ Она позволит взаимодействовать с таблицами, а так же записывать/забирать данные из таблиц Google, дальше с данными необходимо уже поработать через `aiogram`

Comment: Данная библиотека от и до зависит от данных передаваемые через API Google. Что такое API -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893865/%d0%94%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-api

Comment: Как начать пользоваться Google API вместе с Python -> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python?hl=en

Comment: @Acinit Спасибо! Пойду изучать